# Complex Integration example

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Suppose I'm asked to compute the value of the complex integral:
$$\int_{C}^{}\frac{\operatorname{Log}(z)}{z}\,dz$$ with $C=[i,1].$

Is it possible to treat the complex integrand like a real one and apply the rules of integration with limits $i$ to $1$, or do I ought to parameterize the given curve and then treat it like a line integral?

Comment: It's not clear what $C=[i,1]$ means. How are you getting from $i$ to $1$?

Comment: How do you define $\log z$?

Comment: C is the line segment from i to 1 and Logz is the complex logarithm.

Comment: @Andrew Tzevas: In that case, since your path never crosses a pole and is analytic on a domain containing the path, I think you could simply compute the antiderivative and use the fundamental theorem for line integrals.

Comment: $z = \mathrm{i} + \left(1 -\mathrm{i}\right)t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a holomorphic function is defined  on an open set containing the smooth curve and  when the function also has an antiterivative there, yes you can estimate the integral as the difference of the values of the anti-derivative on the endpoints of your curve. Any proper  introductory complex analysis textbook will include this

Comment: An the answe is ... ?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,
-\ \overbrace{\int_{1}^{\epsilon}{\ln\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\mbox{over}\,\,\, \pars{1,\epsilon}}}\ -\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\ln\pars{\epsilon} + \ic\theta \over \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}\,
\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta}
^{\ds{\mbox{over}\,\,\, \epsilon\expo{\ic\pars{0,\pi/2}}}}\ -\
\overbrace{\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln\pars{y} + \ic\pi/2 \over \ic y}\,\ic\,\dd y}
^{\ds{\mbox{over}\,\,\,\pars{\ic\epsilon,\ic}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{\epsilon} -
\bracks{\ic\ln\pars{\epsilon}\,{\pi \over 2} -
\color{#f00}{\pi^{2} \over 8}} - \bracks{-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{\epsilon} -\ic\ln\pars{\epsilon}\,{\pi \over 2}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\Large \to}\,\,\,
\bbx{\pi^{2} \over 8}
\end{align}